# What is the language Santa Claus speaks with the elves?

Tags: languages, the-christmas-chronicles

In the 2020 film *[The Christmas Chronicles 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Christmas_Chronicles_2)*, we hear Santa Claus speaking Elvish with the Elves. Katie turns out to speak it as well. I can't recall if that language was used in the first film as well.

We hear a bit of it in the following scene.

What is that language? Is it an existing language? Is it based on one?

Comment: I distictly heard "Lugbúrz"

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A semi-nonsensical '*nordic sounding*' language that the inventor has dubbed "***Yulish***", but is referred to in the script and novelisations as "***Elvish***"

> Elvish was developed by David J. Peterson, a renowned language creator in the world of TV and film. His most notable work was creating Dothraki and High Valyrian for the hit HBO series, *Game of Thrones*. Peterson also made languages featured in *The 100*, *Penny Dreadful*, *The Witcher*, and *Lovecraft Country* in addition to movies like *Thor: The Dark World*, *Doctor Strange*, and *Bright*. Peterson's expert language creation skills will soon be on display in Denis Villeneuve's *Dune*, set to release in 2021.
>
> Despite the fact that *The Christmas Chronicles* classified the language as "Elvish," Peterson considered it to be "Yulish." He invented it to be the official language spoken by Santa Claus and the large number of Christmas elves that resided in the North Pole. Yulish purposely used a nonpast tense and the main stress in the pronunciation featured a dip in the pitch. The elves, of course, had higher-pitched voices based on their size. If ***The Christmas Chronicles 2*** hits the same level of popularity as the original movie, the elves will certainly be back for another installment.
>
> <sub><sup>[The Christmas Chronicles 2: What Language The Elves Speak](https://screenrant.com/christmas-chronicles-2-elves-language-speak-elvish-nordic/)</sup></sub>

Interestingly, you can see the construction for this language [here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:kwnCqxYhgcEJ:dedalvs.com/work/the-christmas-chronicles-2/misc/yulish_pronunciation.pdf%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=ch).

Comment: “I am Yutz’z Yo’urden. I have forsaken my people, the elves of the North. Fear my twin candy canes: Twinkle and Icingdeath!”